# Error when using DependencyResolver for Controller instantiation with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I'm using MVC 3 and using the following code when the application starts...

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

new UnityMappings(container);

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityServiceLocator(container));
```

Now when the app runs I'm getting the following error (but only sometimes)...

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   IControllerFactory, key ""

Interestingly, if I continue with the web request, the website works normally.

Any ideas? I can't see what I'm doing differently from before when this worked fine.

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: Where are you creating the container, in global.asax or using WebActivator? Also, which webserver are you using? IIS, IISExpress or VS Dev server/Cassini?

Comment: The code above is running in a method called from Application_Start().

Comment: Oh dear... there's another one... `Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ModelMetadataProvider, key ""`

Comment: This appears to be an environment issue because the exceptions aren't being thrown on a different machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MVC3 requests a lot more than just controllers from the `DependencyResolver`. For most of them MVC3 falls back to the default implementation in case the DependencyResolver does not return an instance.

In your case it requests the `IControllerFactory` which is unknown to your IoC container and it throws an exception which is caught by the `UnityServiceLocator` implementation and null is returned. MVC then falls back to the default controller factory.

Unlike other IoC containers Unity does not provide an optional `TryResolve` and therefore does not support a proper exceptionless implementation of the `DependencyResolver`.

Comment: Hi Rmo! This code has worked for me before without throwing this exception. Also, I don't see how it can be falling back on the default controller factory because its passing custom constructor parameters to the controller (which are supplied by Unity).

Comment: The default controller factory implementation of MVC3 uses the DependencyResolver to get controllers. Almost everyone uses the default one. And as you say your application works. Just with the problem that an exception is thrown, cached and the fallback is used.

Comment: So what do you think it is about my environment as opposed to others that's making these exceptions be thrown?

Comment: From the little information you have given it sounds like you see the error only in the debugger due to the exception settings in VS (Ctrl-Alt-E). Clear all the checkmarks in the thrown column there. The exception most likely occurs on every system and is catched on every system.

Comment: Everything was already unchecked except User Handled CLR Exceptions. Unchecking that seems to have worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first looking through the config and make sure everything is correct there, then I would make sure I had all the assemblies needed for Unity referenced in the project. That error message may (in my experience) point to an error in config or a missing DLL, perhaps an assembly you want to load in the container or another DLL needed by a DLL loaded by Unity?

Hope this helps.